# Looking for a specific type of keyboard

Tags: keyboards

I remember having a keyboard, a few years back, where the **keycaps** on the columns of letters were **alternately concave/convex**, i.e. QAZ concave, WSX convex, EDC concave etc. (or the opposite). I have found entirely convex keyboards, but I cannot find this particular kind. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems rather too broad for us to effectively answer at the moment. Could you add more detail to the question? There should be as much detail as possible - what price range, any preferences on build, manufacturers - any details you can think of.

Comment: I don't really remember anything, I am looking for any keyboard which satsifies this requirement.
To clarify, the keys of every column were convex/concave, i.e. QAZ concave, WSX convex, EDC concave etc. (or the opposite).

Comment: @Elad, you're talking about the keycaps themselves rather than the positions of the keys relative to each other?

Comment: @Mark, yes. Some of the keycaps were convex, other were concave, which made touch typing easy.

Comment: @Elad, are you looking for something like this? http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Cordless-Desktop-Ergonomic-Keyboard/dp/B001DJ9GOS

Comment: @belford Thanks for the comment but no, the keycaps of all the letters on the keyboard you linked to are concave, I am looking for a keyboard where some of the keycaps are convex.

Comment: @Elad, check this one also http://allthingsergo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/kinesis-black-in-use-side.jpg. Add more details to your question and we will try to help you.

Comment: @Elad: for what it's worth, I found your question clear and precise.  I do not know of any such hardware, tho, sorry.

Comment: What would your budget be?

Comment: So does theyboard have a wave like design to the keys?